# How to sort a Map by value in multi layer

Tags: java, sorting

Here is the map with the following structure:

```
Map<String, Oddcurve> curves;

class Oddcurve entends Curve {
    private String curvename;
}

class Curve {
    private int curveId;
    protected Set<CurvePoint> points = new TreeSet();
}

class CurvePoint {
    private double time;
    private double value;
}
```

I want to sort the curves by the time ASC, and finally return still the same map :

```
proxyCurves.entrySet().stream().sorted(Comparator.comparing(Map.Entry::getValue));
```

I write in this way, When i debug it, I can see that the sorting works fine, but finally still returns the original curves, I don't know why?

```
proxyCurves.values().stream().forEach(curve -> curve.setPoints(curve.getPoints().stream().sorted(new ComparableComparator<>()).collect(Collectors.toSet())));
```

Comment: You can't sort a map on the values. You can only sort it on the keys.

Comment: You should provide valid code snippets (see [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) to demonstrate what you have and what you tried. The above would not work as it is, as `CurvePoint` doesn't implement `Comparable` it cannot be added to `points`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Firstly, I would advise you to override `hashCode()` and `equals()`
  methods (you may run into issues because of that).
- Secondly, I would advise you to implement `Comparable`
  interface in `CurvePoint` class because you are using `TreeSet`. Then you will be able to override
  `compareTo()` method, and define your way of sorting.

Comment: yes, I write this way, When i debug it, I can see that the sorting works, but finally still returns the original curves, I don't know why?

Comment: @QSY I see below that you were able to solve your issue, good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is the code I use to solve the problem:

```
curves.values().stream().forEach(
            curve -> {
                final Set<CurvePoint> sortedPoints = new TreeSet<>(
                        (curvePoint1, curvePoint2) -> Double.compare(curvePoint1.getTime(), curvePoint2.getTime()));
                sortedPoints.addAll(curve.getPoints());
                curve.setPoints(sortedPoints);
            });
```